# Query expression with join on multi part key and nullables

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, query-expressions

Consider the following two tables, with 3 columns each:

Table 1:

```
a INTEGER NOT NULL,
b INTEGER NOT NULL,
c INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Table 2:

```
d INTEGER NOT NULL,
e INTEGER,
f INTEGER NOT NULL
```

I'm trying to write a query expression that joins the two tables on a 2 part, composite key: `(b, c) = (e, f)`.

I know that if column `e` was not `Nullable` I could just write:

```
query {
    for r1 in c.table1 do
    join r2 in c.table2 on ((r1.b, r1.c) = (r2.e, r2.f))
    .
    .
}
```

But how do I do it if column `e` is `Nullable` but column `b` in not?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but what happens if you try `r2.e.Value` instead of `r2.e` inside the tuple?

Comment: Well, I think the same thing as if I do `((Nullable(r1.b), r1.c) = (r2.e, r2.f))`: basically an exception if `r2.e` is `Null`. What I think we need here is a `Nullable` tuple type, so that the `?=` can be used.

Comment: What exception do you see using `Nullable(r1.b)`?  It shouldn't be a null reference exception since equality comparisons are valid even on nulls.

Comment: @kvb: It's an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Thrown when the query is compiled to SQL or when the results are requested?  Is it the same exception when you do `r2.e.Value`?

Comment: I'm sorry this is my bad. The exception occurs because I call `head` in the query exception after the join and the sequence is empty. So I guess `Nullable(r1.b)` does actually work.